# How to Deserialize complex JSON object using c#?

Tags: c#, .net, json, deserialization, jsonconverter

> > How to Deserialize complex JSON object using c#, Please i to need
> >     DeSerialize the JSON string in following? i tried to put the
> >     transaction property as a dictionary and not working so please any
> >     idea ?
> >
> > Exception when replace transaction from array to dictionary  :  Cannot serialize member wsA2AEBS.WCTransactionsResponse1.transactions
> >     of type System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String,
> >     mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> >     PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[wsA2AEBS.WCTransInfoRes, wsA2AEBS,
> >     Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], because it
> >     implements IDictionary. Description: An unhandled exception occurred
> >     during the execution of the current web request. Please review the
> >     stack trace for more information about the error and where it
> >     originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.NotSupportedException: Cannot serialize
>   member wsA2AEBS.WCTransactionsResponse1.transactions of type
>   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[wsA2AEBS.WCTransInfoRes, wsA2AEBS,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], because it
>   implements IDictionary.
>
> ---------- JSON File

```
{
            ""applicationId"": ""ONB"",
            ""tranDateTime"": ""300817114023"",
            ""UUID"": ""e8289a8e-b522-4c56-b6df-d15b8cecb5d6"",
            ""responseStatus"": ""Successful"",
            ""responseCode"": 1,
            ""responseMessage"": ""Approved"",
            ""consumerIdentifier"": ""249915513503"",
            ""isConsumer"": true,
            ""fee"": 0.0,
            ""transactions"": {
                ""750271185417"": {
                    ""amount"": ""0.00"",
                    ""fee"": ""0"",
                    ""customerPayeeId"": """",
                    ""destinationIdentifier"": """",
                    ""status"": ""COMPLETED"",
                    ""payeeId"": """",
                    ""billId"": """",
                    ""externalFee"": ""0.00"",
                    ""type"": ""GET_TRANSACTIONS"",
                    ""sourceIdentifier"": ""300136232415"",
                    ""transactionName"": """"
                },
                ""750724170249"": {
                    ""amount"": ""0.00"",
                    ""fee"": ""0"",
                    ""customerPayeeId"": """",
                    ""destinationIdentifier"": """",
                    ""status"": ""COMPLETED"",
                    ""payeeId"": """",
                    ""billId"": """",
                    ""externalFee"": ""0.00"",
                    ""type"": ""GET_TRANSACTIONS"",
                    ""sourceIdentifier"": ""300136232415"",
                    ""transactionName"": """"
                },
                ""752569664009"": {
                    ""amount"": ""0.00"",
                    ""fee"": ""0"",
                    ""customerPayeeId"": """",
                    ""destinationIdentifier"": """",
                    ""status"": ""COMPLETED"",
                    ""payeeId"": """",
                    ""billId"": """",
                    ""externalFee"": ""0.00"",
                    ""type"": ""GET_TRANSACTIONS"",
                    ""sourceIdentifier"": ""300136232415"",
                    ""transactionName"": """"
                },
                ""750774501897"": {
                    ""amount"": ""0.00"",
                    ""fee"": ""0"",
                    ""customerPayeeId"": """",
                    ""destinationIdentifier"": """",
                    ""status"": ""COMPLETED"",
                    ""payeeId"": """",
                    ""billId"": """",
                    ""externalFee"": ""0.00"",
                    ""type"": ""GET_TRANSACTIONS"",
                    ""sourceIdentifier"": ""300136232415"",
                    ""transactionName"": """"
                },
                ""752401891849"": {
                    ""amount"": ""0.00"",
                    ""fee"": ""0"",
                    ""customerPayeeId"": """",
                    ""destinationIdentifier"": """",
                    ""status"": ""COMPLETED"",
                    ""payeeId"": """",
                    ""billId"": """",
                    ""externalFee"": ""0.00"",
                    ""type"": ""GET_TRANSACTIONS"",
                    ""sourceIdentifier"": ""300136232415"",
                    ""transactionName"": """"
                },
                ""753475633673"": {
                    ""amount"": ""0.00"",
                    ""fee"": ""0"",
                    ""customerPayeeId"": """",
                    ""destinationIdentifier"": """",
                    ""status"": ""COMPLETED"",
                    ""payeeId"": """",
                    ""billId"": """",
                    ""externalFee"": ""0.00"",
                    ""type"": ""GET_BALANCE"",
                    ""sourceIdentifier"": ""300136232415"",
                    ""transactionName"": """"
                },
                ""702396401949"": {
                    ""amount"": ""1.00"",
                    ""fee"": ""0"",
                    ""customerPayeeId"": """",
                    ""destinationIdentifier"": ""249915513503"",
                    ""status"": ""COMPLETED"",
                    ""payeeId"": """",
                    ""billId"": """",
                    ""externalFee"": ""0"",
                    ""type"": ""CASH_IN"",
                    ""sourceIdentifier"": ""313827219935"",
                    ""transactionName"": """"
                },
                ""751328150025"": {
                    ""amount"": ""0.00"",
                    ""fee"": ""0"",
                    ""customerPayeeId"": """",
                    ""destinationIdentifier"": """",
                    ""status"": ""COMPLETED"",
                    ""payeeId"": """",
                    ""billId"": """",
                    ""externalFee"": ""0.00"",
                    ""type"": ""GET_TRANSACTIONS"",
                    ""sourceIdentifier"": ""300136232415"",
                    ""transactionName"": """"
                },
                ""753391747593"": {
                    ""amount"": ""0.00"",
                    ""fee"": ""0"",
                    ""customerPayeeId"": """",
                    ""destinationIdentifier"": """",
                    ""status"": ""COMPLETED"",
                    ""payeeId"": """",
                    ""billId"": """",
                    ""externalFee"": ""0.00"",
                    ""type"": ""GET_TRANSACTIONS"",
                    ""sourceIdentifier"": ""300136232415"",
                    ""transactionName"": """"
                },
                ""750422180361"": {
                    ""amount"": ""0.00"",
                    ""fee"": ""0"",
                    ""customerPayeeId"": """",
                    ""destinationIdentifier"": """",
                    ""status"": ""COMPLETED"",
                    ""payeeId"": """",
                    ""billId"": """",
                    ""externalFee"": ""0.00"",
                    ""type"": ""GET_BALANCE"",
                    ""sourceIdentifier"": ""300136232415"",
                    ""transactionName"": """"
                }
            },
            ""transactionId"": ""754046059017""
        }
```

> ---------- Classes

```
public class WCTransactionsResponse
    {
        public string applicationId;
        public string tranDateTime;
        public string UUID;
        public string consumerIdentifier;
        public bool isConsumer;
        public string extraData;
        //public string notifyConsumer;
        //public string tranFeeAmount;
        //public string feeSource;
        //public string feeShare;
        public string responseStatus;
        public string responseCode;
        public string responseMessage;
        public string fee;
        public WCTransInfoRes[] transactions;
        public string transactionId;
    }



public class WCTransInfoRes
    {
        public string status;
        public string type;
        public string amount;
        public string fee;
        public string externalFee;
        public string sourceIdentifier;
        public string destinationIdentifier;
        public string billId;
        public string payeeId;
        public string customerPayeeId;
        public string transactionName;
    }
```

> ---------- Convert Json String

```
 WCTransactionsResponse Resp = new WCTransactionsResponse();

            var json = File.ReadAllText(@"E:\wsA2AEBS\wsA2AEBS\json.json");
            //var jObject = JObject.Parse(json);

            Resp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WCTransactionsResponse>(json);

            return Resp;// jObject.ToString();
```

Comment: all those double quotes make the JSON invalid

Comment: the problem not in double quotes, the proble in transaction list

Comment: Since you did not tell us the problem or error, just *not working*  it is certainly a problem for anyone wanting to help you!!!  Some of the data types are wrong too (`Fee` is decimal/double not string).

Comment: @Plutonix, Actually the double quotes makes it easy to copy to visual studio into a  verbatim string....

Comment: Are you sure that the structure of you class WCTransactionsResponse (property ordering , property data type) is correct ?

If yes what is your problem did you received exception ?

Comment: the exception i had when i put the data type of  transactions member 
public Dictionary<string, WCTransInfoRes> transactions;
 
Cannot serialize member wsA2AEBS.WCTransactionsResponse1.transactions of type System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[wsA2AEBS.WCTransInfoRes, wsA2AEBS, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], because it implements IDictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You say it's a dictionary, but you declare it as array.

Change the definition to `Dictionary`:

```
public Dictionary<string, WCTransInfoRes> transactions;
```

Comment: i have exception when run the service 

Cannot serialize member wsA2AEBS.WCTransactionsResponse1.transactions of type System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[wsA2AEBS.WCTransInfoRes, wsA2AEBS, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], because it implements IDictionary.